# Как сделать нижнюю часть слева div поднятой , а правую часть div нижнюю отпустить вниз?

Tags: html, css

[image: вот так]

Я пробывал задавать контейнеру `transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg) skewY(26deg);` и ребенку задавал `transform: skewY(336deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg)`: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но верхние углы тоже изменяются

Answer (score 1):

Используй свойство:

```
clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 100% 0px, 97.5% 392px, 1px 76.50%);
```

Если нужно удобно редактировать, то используй firefox developer edition (пример работы) - https://habrastorage.org/webt/yf/jk/ux/yfjkuxg3tuyo9thkkiowowt3jdy.gif